How to solve error ErrImagePull when pulling a Docker image from DockerHub into GKE?
I'm trying to run a web app in Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE).
The container image is stored in a private repository in DockerHub.
When I try to pull the image from the repository of DockerHub into GKE, I get the errors shown in the attached image: ErrImgPull.
I checked that the GKE cluster is public and I checked that the tag attribute in the yaml kubernetes matches with the tag of the image in DockerHub.
The credentials of DockerHub that I've stored are correct. The password is the access token.
How could I solve this issue?

Need more details... Do you specify imagePullSecrets in the spec of your pod?

Exactly, that was what I was missing.
I solved the issue this past hour by following the next tutorial: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/
